# How does string.split evaluate a string with only delimiters?

Tags: java

For example

```
String splits[] = ("||").split("[|]")
```

`System.out.println(splits.length)`  returns 0.  Whereas I expected it to return 2.  Whats the best way to solve this problem ?

Comment: why do you have a square bracket around the pipe delimiter ?

Comment: @rahul: to make it character literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default operation of `split()` is to discard trailing empty strings. Since every resulting string is empty, no strings will be returned.

More precisely, calling [`split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is the same as calling [`split(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with the second parameter set to 0.

And 0 means (emphasis mine):

> ...  the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and *trailing empty strings will be discarded.*

If you want to keep trailing empty strings (and don't want to limit the number of elements), then pass in a negative value (I'd suggest -1):

```
String splits[] = "||".split("\\|", -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

When split is called on a string that ends with the delimiter, the ending delimiter(s) are just discarded.

for example, all of these are the same:

```
"X|Y|Z|||".split([|]).length
"X|Y|Z||".split([|]).length
"X|Y|Z|".split([|]).length
"X|Y|Z".split([|]).length
```

_note that you put `|` in bracket, since `|` is a meta-character in regular expressions.